# Using DataBinding values to update Width of a Control (WPF)

Tags: wpf, data-binding, width

I created a user control and an associated view model. The properties "DisplayName" and "TimeIntervalLength" of the view model are displayed in the user control view DataBinding. Depending on those properties of the view model I want to update the width of my control.
The width should be "TimeIntervalLength" but at least "DisplayName". I tried to override "OnPropertyChanged" but this does not work. Further I could not find an appropriated event to override.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help in determining the root cause if you could post up how you have your bindings declared. It could be a variety of different issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try just not specifying a Width/Height on your UserControl. It should fit to the controls hosted within.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" Text="DisplayName Goes Here" />
        <local:TimeIntervalControl x:Name="TimeInterval" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Another option is to use an [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to do some heavier lifting:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:MaxValueConverter x:Key="MaxValue" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.Width>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MaxValue}">
            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="TextBlock1" />
            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="TimeInterval" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </UserControl.Width>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" Text="DisplayName Goes Here" />
        <local:TimeIntervalControl x:Name="TimeInterval" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Heavy lifting in your MaxValueConverter:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
   if (values == null)
   {
       return Binding.DoNothing;
   }

   return values.Max(obj => (obj is double) ? (double)obj : 0.0);
}
```

Comment: Meta comment: ActualWidth does not always show that is has changed, esp if you apply a LayoutTransform. You may have to add additional logic to cause the binding to re-evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if I understand correctly, but it sounds like the easiest thing to do would be to add a calculated property to your ViewModel and then bind to that from the View:

```
// In your model
public int DisplayWidth {
    get { return CalculateDisplayWidth(); } // todo
}
```

(Obviously you can replace "CalculateDisplayWidth()" with whatever you need)

```
<!-- In your view -->
<UserControl x:Class="MyUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Width="{Binding Path=DisplayWidth, Mode=OneWay}">

</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of controlling Width, control **MinWidth**. And clear the Width property in the constructor of UserControl:

```
this.ClearValue(WidthProperty);
```